# Are the apocalyptic conditions shown in interstellar possible?

Tags: interstellar

It is shown that people focused on technology and the food became scarce... Etc. The grandpa also mentions that new things came every other day...  Are we approaching the same fate?

Comment: This question seems to ask for an evaluation for current real-life ecological situation. As such, this questions is off topic on this site.

Comment: Which site should it be posted then

Comment: You should most probably try [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) or [Sceptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/). In that order.

Comment: @Gallifreian Or possibly [worldbuilding.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the crop wilting, no.

In interstellar there was a plague that seemed to affect all crop plants. Such a thing is very unlikely to naturally occur.

However:

There is of course global warming which could affect a lot of agricultural land, reducing it's effectiveness and the less well known but just as scary Soil Erosion (where intensive agriculture erodes the soil which eventually becomes unproductive) This could produce very similar circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

In Interstellar the food became scarce due to plagues that killed the food crops.

Is it possible to happen? Yes. Is it likely? No.

There are plenty of diseases that kill crops in real life, although they are usually contained to a location, and not widespread (like the human plagues, which spread worldwide due to human's high mobility). One example of crop disease would be Wheat's powdery mildew. You can create GMO's resistant to this fungus though, or use a fungicide.

It is somewhat easy to create GMO's resistant to one or more disease. If the world was starving, all the anti-GMO soccer moms wouldn't be so afraid of GMOs either. So it'd need to be a super "disease" for starters, that we couldn't eradicate. On top of that, it'd need to be a disease that affected all the crops, all kinds of fruit, etc. So it becomes a very unlikely scenario, since we never seen such disease in plant-life.

Comment: Yes, good answer (even if the question is a little off topic). The disease in *Interstellar* is specifically a "blight", which is an umbrella term, that afflicted edible plants. There are several examples of more species-specific blights in history that have caused food scarcities. The Irish Potato Famine is the most famous example, which killed about 1 million people.

Comment: The risk of GMO is  monoculture: the vast majority of production is one species and largely clones.  The wrong disease tears through it like wildfire and kills it ALL.  It sounds like in that era, they were doubling down on GMO crops, always looking for the next gene-splice that is immune to last year's disease but making it vulnerable to next year's.  They didn't know how to do biodiversity anymore,  Possibly repeated crop failures had also wrecked the land, dust bowl style.